# SQL statements performance review

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I have SQL statements generated by .NET Entity Framework 3.5 (already did optimization on EF 3.5, and we will soon upgrade to 4), and run on a 2005 SQL Server. I know there are a lot of articles talking about SQL performance in general, but I didn't find a specific solution to my problem.
I need a reference or a solution to this situation:
In an ASP.NET application there is a table with certain information (something like 6-7 columns), and when the user performs a sort action on the tables, it takes 7-15 seconds to retrieve the information (... this is bad performance since the application is business internal).

I ran usp_Worst_TSQL from the article:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3802936/Finding-the-Worst-Performing-T-SQL-Statements-on-an-Instance.htm and I get where the performance issues come from: there are several nested queries that use WHERE, INNER & LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY clauses.

What are the considerations for creating Indexes regarding the SQL statements clauses in statements?
and when do I need to make composite indexes?

EDIT:
I managed to get an idea from where the problem is. I have this LINQ and foreach loop in the code, which takes 3 full seconds to get the data:

```
foreach (string status in searchObj.Statuses)
{
from f in tblFormsQO
where f.tblFormStatus.Count > 0 && f.tblFormStatus.Count(s => s.StatusDate == null) == 0
&& f.tblFormStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.StatusDate).FirstOrDefault().CurrentStatus.CodeDesc == status
select f
}
```

Now, f is not a BIG entity (and I do need all its properties).
Is there any way to make it perform better?

Comment: This is the kind of questions that it takes courage to write an answer.  Mix generated sql from EF with performance issue and not code sample in sentence.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide a lot of scope for an answer but I would suggest that if its taking 7-15s to execute a query, its probably not written very well. An index may improve performance but you should look carefully at what the query is actually attempting if its nested. I wrote a cheat sheet for getting the best from EF Performance which is available here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/08/entity-framework-performance-cheat-sheet.html. I would suggest you are in the orange box

Comment: Yep, I know, I'll edit the question... :-) ... the problem is that the generated queries are so long, that I think I'll need 3 questions just to display the important parts of the query...

Comment: WOW, good comment, Luke McGregor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times does that foreach loop get iterated over on average?  You could load the data into memory first and then using linq on the cached data would be much faster than the multiple sql statements that the foreach potentially generates.

That may not address the root of the problem, but just a suggestion I can give based on what I see.

EDIT:

Your original question had to do with considerations for indexes.  I would find out what the actual queries being sent are and then run them in SQL Management Studio yourself with the option to generate the execution plan turned on.  That way you can get suggestions from SQL on indexes that could potentially speed up the queries.

As for considerations about adding indexes in general, it's only an issue if you're worried about speed of inserting/deleting data.  The more indexes you have the more it will slow those operations down.  Otherwise, add all the indexes you like.  And make sure you have a clustered index as that will potentially speed all your other indexes up.

Comment: Thanks, there can be up to 9 loops in the foreach... The problem is that in tblFormsQO, there maybe be a lot of records - this is why I cannot cache all tblFormsQO records and do the work on them... This is a tradeoff issue.

Comment: You 'could' construct a single query that got all the statuses at once though (unless you're saying it's so much data that you can only work with the records for one status at a time).  But I agree that this is not the root of the issue.  However, depending on your situation you might be able to multithread the forloop so they all process at the same time.  Probably not an option I'm guessing, but just thought I'd throw that out there in case it might be.

Comment: That is, for all the statuses that the forloop would have picked up... not for 'all' statuses, but hopefully that was obvious what I meant.

Comment: I'll try something and get back to you on that

Comment: @lionheart btw, I added a couple notes regarding indexes to my answer

Comment: I know what the problem in the code example refers to - but in order to rewrite it, I will have to get rid of the loop, which will not work, because Contains for list is not supported in EF 3.5... I'd try using indexes.

Comment: I think we will upgrade this project to .NET 4.0 eventually. Thanks for your time.